# Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Following is the php code to execute sql. But it fails with Catchable fatal error.
And I have read the php manual [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), the sample code is such similar with the code I wrote. I can't figure out the error.

```
$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO note_list (id, date, note)"."VALUES (:id, :date, :note)");
$statement->execute(array(":id" => $count,":date" => $date,":note" => $note));
```

Comment: Is there anything like `echo $statement`? This error means, that you tried to output **object** as **string** (or tried to use object in string context) without declaring magic `__toString()` method.

Comment: no. I search for statement. There are just two position it locates as I shows. Thks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that the line number in the error actually points to those two lines in your code?

Comment: yeah. I am sure.More specific, the second line.

Comment: Fine, then what's `$count`, `$date` and `$note`?

Comment: I can not determine error, from source code you provided. Is there any related code, that might be supplied?

Comment: Oh, the problem is $count.This var is PDOstatement. Thks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$statement->execute(array(":id" => $count,":date" => $date,":note" => $note));
```

If the error occurs on this line, then either `$count`, `$date` or `$note` is an instance of `PDOStatement`. Figure out which one it is and turn them into strings properly.

Comment: Oh, the problem is $count.This var is PDOstatement. $count = $db->query($sql)

Comment: there you go. that should probably be fetchColumn() or something of the sort.